# Different css for Android and iPhone without javascript

Tags: css, html, mobile

Is there a way to use a different css for Android than is used for iPhone without using javascript?

I would like to know this because I want to style some elements differently for the two operating systems.

Comment: You use html5 but don't want to use javascript? good luck with that.

Comment: I prefer not to use javascript for loading the initial css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**. You can't i think. there is no bulletproof method to detect these two type of devices clearly, because of **a lot of variety** and **great number** of devices with quite different *software* and *hardware* settings and having different resolutions.